# How to get Youtube Live Stream by Channel Id in Youtube API V3 in android?

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am able to get the list of live stream: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list#examples
But how to get the live stream status and live stream link or id for particular channel using youtube v3 api in android?

Comment: did you get any ANS?

Comment: No ANS if you get any plz share it.

Comment: i am also looking for this. but what about scrap the youtube channel and get the url of live stream ?

Comment: Still no answers? Did you found a solution? I need also need to get the live stream videos available from a channel id.

Comment: @hsantos I have added an answer for the same, if you are still looking for a solution.

Comment: @AmeerHamza have added a solution

Comment: thank man i already have done this,

Comment: @AmeerHamza can you post the answer or any link here so that it will be useful for all

Comment: ok i add the code

Comment: you can now check @YLS i added the code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have faced the same problem and managed to figure out a solution for the same. YouTube actually provides an API for this purpose. You can use the search API to get the currently active Live Video ID, if you have the channel ID.

Use the following API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={YOUR_CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The key factor here is you have to set the `eventType` to `live` and `type` to `video`.

For getting the channel ID, you can use the following request, if you have the channel's username.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={CHANNEL_USER_NAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: This only works for PUBLIC livestreams. Does not work for UNLISTED or PRIVATE livestreams.

Comment: My live streaming is PUBLIC and LISTED but still no results on api request https://prnt.sc/p8qce3

Comment: @GastonCoroleu I'm having a similar issue. I was using the above code snippet for a while until it stopped working about a week ago. Not too sure as to why

Comment: @GastonCorole Please verify if there is any limit exceeding issue. I just tried after seeing these comments, it is still working for me. Checked the API documentation, there is no change there as well.

Comment: @SteppingHat Please verify as well

Comment: @Harikrishnan Usage limits were the first thing I checked. I was always way under the quota as I make a maximum of 5 calls a day due to a rate limiting/caching layer. To further troubleshooting I also created a new property on another account and ran the same query with the same result on the main property. However it seems to be working again for some odd reason as of a few days ago. Not too sure what was going on there

Comment: I confirm, this api call hasn't been working in September 2019. Now it works, yay!

Comment: Looks like this api call is not working anymore can anyone confirm?

Comment: Im trying to get all live streams for this channel but it returns no resuls https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXzGWycANrrfyBmzX6JMsvQ/live

Answer (score 7):

This will return live stream ID

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can also pass Query to YouTube so YouTube give you all live stream events

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q={YOUR_SEARCH_QuERY}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_YOUTUBE_API}
```

This how i get live stream videos in my app

```
    private void initVolley(String[] urls) {


        for (String url : urls) {

            if (url.startsWith("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/")) {
                jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                            if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                                for (int getItem = 0; getItem < jsonArray.length(); getItem++) {

                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(getItem).getJSONObject("id");
                                    String videoID = jsonObject.getString("videoId");


                                    Log.d(TAG, "void id " + videoID);

                                    mUrlList.add(new video(jsonArray.getJSONObject(getItem).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(getItem).getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium").getString("url"), " ", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID, true));


                                    if (mAdapter != null)
                                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    Log.d(TAG, videoID + jsonArray.length() + jsonArray.getJSONObject(getItem).getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("default").getString("url"));

                                }

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        }
}
```

And if you have YouTube links maybe you store  your in database then this will return you some usefull info with out API key

```
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUOhCtXPN40&format=json
```

and below code for this

```
     JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonURL, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                // mVideo = new video(response.getString("title"), response.getString("thumbnail_url"), response.getString("author_name"));
                                //  mVideoDataSet.add(mVideo);

                                mVideo = new video(url);
                                mVideo.setVideoTitle(response.getString("title"));
                                mVideo.setVideoThimailUrl(response.getString("thumbnail_url"));
                                mVideo.setVideoChannalName(response.getString("author_name"));
                                mVideo.setLiveNow(false);
                                mVideoDataSet.add( mVideo);
                                Log.d(TAG, "inside the volly" + mVideo.getVideoTitle());
                               // Log.d(TAG, mVideoDataSet.get(i).getVideoStreemUrl());



                                if (mAdapter != null) {
                                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                                    if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
//                                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "setingAdupter");
//                                    if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
//                                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                   mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mVideoDataSet);
                                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                                }
                                i++;
                                if (i != mUrlList.size())
                                    initVolly();


                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                           // if(error)
                          i++;
                            initVolly();
                            Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                        }
                    }
            );
            // Adds the JSON object request "obreq" to the request queue
requestQueue.add(obreq);
```

and last if you want to see source code here [is link](https://github.com/ameerhamza6733/ameerhamza6733.championtrophy2017schedule/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ameerhamza6733/championtrophy2017schedule/fragments/Live.java#L234)

Comment: This only works for PUBLIC livestreams. Does not work for UNLISTED or PRIVATE livestreams.

Comment: i think it make sense because they are private