# Using YouTube API, how to get the video id for a live stream from the channel name?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-data-api

There are 3 ways that i can access a stream from a channel /live:

- https://youtube.com/channel/channel_id/live
- https://youtube.com/user/username/live
- https://youtube.com/c/channel_name/live

I know how to get it from the channel_id and i know how to get the channel_id from the username. My problem is on the 3rd case. Is it possible to get the channel_id from this custom URL?

Second question. The way i get the video URL from the channel id is using the following endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I've notice that if the channel has a live stream going on at /channel-id/live and have other stream on with specific URL I have no warranty that the video URL that i get is the one associated with the /channel-id/live. Is that a way to get this specific video?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is pretty old but I recently faced this issue as well and was able to find an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521853/how-to-get-youtube-live-stream-by-channel-id-in-youtube-api-v3-in-android) SO post.

Basically, take the `CHANNEL_ID` and utilize YouTube's Search endpoint like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

This request will return a `youtube#video` object that contains the `videoId`