# android - How to live stream YouTube channel(e.g. Mecca Live) with in your app?

Tags: android, youtube, live-streaming

I'm adding live streaming feature to my android app. I'm streaming Makkah Live channel using youtube player but the problem i'm facing is that video ID changes changes after every 2-3 days. Could you please guide me whether I've to pay to YouTube or to respective channel to retain same video ID or what else the solution is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Youtube API call that's return only live stream events(video) from XYZ youtube channel. Then grab that video ID and use Youtube player to play video

> This will return live stream IDs From XYZ channel

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I already give this [Question ANS Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44900320/5727285)